# heart shaped picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Is it possible to make a heart shaped picturebox in c#? 
I have seen codes in making rectangle and ellipse but I don't have any idea  on making a heart shaped region.

Any idea?

Comment: Is this a WPF/Winforms/ASP/XNA question?  Please tag it with the relevant framework you are using :)  Also please post some code, if you have any.

Comment: `Heart shaped region` - make one with [bezier curves](http://www.google.com/search?q=bezier+heart).

Comment: Its in a winform, sadly, i dont have any idea on how to make a heart shape,

Comment: Beware, DuckDuckGo users. The "bezier curves" link is a Google link. [Here's a DuckDuckGo link for the same search term.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bezier+heart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
public class HeartPictureBox : PictureBox {
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe) {
        using (System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath()) {
            path.AddBezier(this.Width >> 1,
                            this.Height >> 2,
                            this.Width * 1.25f, 0f,
                            this.Width,
                            this.Height * 0.75f,
                            this.Width >> 1,
                            this.Height);
            path.AddBezier(this.Width >> 1,
                            this.Height >> 2,
                            -this.Width * .25f, 0f,
                            0f,
                            this.Height * 0.75f,
                            this.Width >> 1,
                            this.Height);

            this.Region = new Region(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Bezier stuff from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/177794/Heart-shaped-Form-in-C-2-0

Comment: Why am I having a Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Region' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type' error?

Comment: If you're having this error, `new Region` should be replaced with `new System.Drawing.Region`.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("    o o.o o   ");
            Console.WriteLine("  o         o      ");
            Console.WriteLine("  o         o       ");
            Console.WriteLine("   o       o         ");
            Console.WriteLine("     o    o       ");
            Console.WriteLine("       o         ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
  }}
```

Comment: Not sure how you were planning on having this displayed as a PictureBox control.

Comment: This is a console application, not a PictureBox shape.