# how to create custom labels in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, custom-controls, label

I've given a task to create a picture puzzle using c#. I have to customize a control to act like a tile. what I have in my mind is to create label to act as a puzzle tile. I have no experience in customizing a label control.. If any one can help me with a tutorial for this task It would be a great help.

I'm using windows forms for this project and not WPF.

I've googled but couldn't find any suitable tutorial. Please help me on this.

Thank you.

below is how each piece should look like in the application! A tile class is used to represent each puzzle piece.

[image]

Comment: Have you thought about using panels for Tile..?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you using WinForms or WPF? You'll have to provide info like that if you want people to be able to help (meanwhile a WPF example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms771766(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Is it easy to use WPF for this task! I'm more familiar with windows form applications.

Comment: Do you have a visual on how you want this to look?

Comment: I added an image for a basic idea.

Comment: Follow what this guy does: http://www.jlion.com/blog/2009/02/ive-been-working-on-jigsaw-puzzle.html Here is an example to understand how the [AddBezier function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248003/heart-shaped-picturebox) in the Drawing2D namespace works.

Comment: So, do you want to use WCF or Windows Forms, or do you _know_ yet?

Comment: I'm using Windows forms for this and decided to extend label. any idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to manipulate the design structure of Windows Form controls is through the GDI (Graphics Device Interface). The device context is accessed through System.Drawing. This will allow you to inherit or override a control and create/alter its appearance. I worked with the GDI for about a month. It is not something that's learned overnight. As a quick alternative, you may consider adding puzzle pictures to a button control and coding it up so that if button A is within xx pixels of button B's left edge then A&B background image = a connected picture. Or something along those lines.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6913/Creating-a-professional-looking-GDI-drawn-custom-c